# Why does a Bayesian Filter require random controls?

Tags: kalman-filter, particle-filter, probability

As stated in Probabalistic Robotics, the proof for correctness of a Bayesian Filter relies on the fact that

$$p(x_{t-1}|z_{1:t-1},\ u_{1:t}) = p(x_{t-1}|z_{1:t-1},\ u_{1:t-1})$$

In order to justify this, they say

> $u_t$ can be safely omitted ... for randomly chosen controls

Why is that required? Isn't that true because the control input at time step t cannot possibly effect the state at time t-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easy to see, when you take a look at the bayesian network:
[image]

Now, we eliminate all the variables not given in your equation:
[image]

Based on this baesian network, you can see that $u_t$ has no effect on the other variables and thus can be omitted.

This however would not work for $u_t$s that are not random. If for example $u_t$ would be dependent on $x_{t-1}$. Which means, based on the last position, the actual control is selected:

[image]

Here $u_t$ can not be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I don't agree with your last sentence. `u_t` does not influence `u_{t-1}`, and so it doesn't influence `x_{t-1}`. For what you're saying to be true, the arrow would have to point the other way

Comment: You are right. Check updated answer!

Comment: I accepted your answer hastily, but now I am again unsure. We only care about u_t effecting x_{t-1} right? Not the other way around

Comment: Is it, that the direction of the arrow confuses you? In the last picture: If you know $u_t$, you can reason about $x_{t-1}$. So, $u_t$ must not be omitted. You can search for "Markov  blanket". This describes, when variables are independent.

Comment: It is not about one variable effecting another variable. It is about the knowledge of one variable giving you information about the other variable.

Comment: Similarly, $x_t$ and $x_{t-1}$ are not independent and knowledge of one affects the probability distribution of the other. Also, knowledge of $z_t$ informs about distribution of $x_t$. Arrows seem to indicate cause and effect (in time or not); from the effect one can infer about the cause and vica-versa.

Comment: Isn’t the assumption that $u_t$ independent of $x_{t-1}$ bad? Most control would depend on state of the world...